# What is angularjs $compile double parenthesis

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I 'm a bit worried If I am asking a noob question or if it is a javascript feature that I haven't been able to locate despite plenty of googling

I am adding a simple directive programmatically using $compile and all is working fine.

My question is this line

```
var el = $compile(newElement)($scope);
```

How do the double parenthesis work/ what do they do? Complete code below for reference but its just the parenthesis which I am not sure about.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
   return {
        template: 'Hello',
        restrict: 'E'
    }
});

myApp.controller('mainController', [
    '$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile) {

        $scope.addDirective = function() {
            var newElement = angular.element(document.createElement('my-directive'));
            var el = $compile(newElement)($scope);
            angular.element(document.body).append(el);
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: It's not any advance feature.  `$compile(newElement)` returns a function.  Then that function is immediately called with `$scope`, using the 2nd set of parens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$compile` returns another function.  You can do something similarly:

```
function foo(greeting) {
  return function(target) { console.log(greeting, target) };
}

foo('Hello, ')('world');
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already know that parenthesis in javascript is an function invocation operator (and also grouping). In other words, with `()` operator you call a function. From here it is clear that the code

```
$compile(newElement)($scope);
```

means that result of `$compile(newElement)` is a **function**, so it can be executed. This returned function accepts one parameter - a scope object in which context new DOM element should be compiled.

Answer (score 1):

`$compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude)` returns the Directive `link:` (post-link) function.

```
app.directive('exampleDirective', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { value: '=value'},
        template: template,
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            scope.count = 0;
            scope.increment = function() {
                scope.value++;
            };

        }
    };
}]);
```

In this case, `$compile('<div example-directive></div>');` will return the `link:` function so you can call it with arguments (`scope` as first) and instanciate the context.

Answer (score 1):

It's all just standard Javascript syntax for calling functions. What might be confusing is that `$compile` is a function that returns a function. So

```
$compile(newElement)
```

is itself function, and can be called like any other function, which is what's happening when writing

```
$compile(newElement)($scope);
```

You can break this up into separate lines if you wish, which might make it clearer:

```
var linkFunction = $compile(newElement);
linkFunction($scope);
```

You can refer to the [usage of $compile in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage).

As a side-note, I would be wary of using `$compile` directly: you might be overcomplicating things, and there could be simpler alternatives (it has been very rare that I've ever had to use it).